# Generic Views NoReverseMatch when using {% url %} in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls, django-generic-views

I have a problem to do the reverse command 'url' from the template base.html.

**URLS.conf** my file looks like this:

```
dic_info_artigo = {
                  'queryset': Artigo.modificado.all(),
                  'date_field': 'data_pub',
}

urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
    (r'^$', 'archive_index', dic_info_artigo,'artigos'),

    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$','archive_year', dic_info_artigo,'artigos_ano'),
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/$',
        'archive_month', dic_info_artigo,'artigos_mes'),
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/$',
        'archive_day', dic_info_artigo,'artigos_dia'),
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        'object_detail', dic_info_artigo,'detalhe_artigo'),
)
```

**base.html**

```
<a href="{% url artigos %}"> Artigos </ a>
```

**The error:**

*dictionary update sequence element # 0 has length 1; 2 is required*

Already tried using the parameter 'name=', i change the value , but it did not work

```
url(r'^$', 'archive_index', dic_info_artigo, name='artigos'),
```

What am I doing wrong? Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: What error you are getting when you tried `url(r'^$', 'archive_index', dic_info_artigo, name='artigos'),` ? I think you need to use url() for naming urls.

Comment: I tried this change em my template 
{% url 'artigos' %} 

and my URL.conf
url(r'^$', 'archive_index', dic_info_artigo, name='artigos'),

but the same error continue...

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that you have tried to name a view using something like:

```
(r'^my_url$', 'my_view', 'my_view')
```

However, the third argument should be a dictionary, not the name of a view.

To prevent errors like this, I recommend always using the `url` shortcut and naming the url pattern:

```
url(r'^my_url$', 'my_view', name='my_view')
```

However, you could pass an empty dictionary as the third argument if prefer:

```
(r'^my_url$', 'my_view', {}, 'my_view')
```

The `urls.py` you have posted looks ok, so the problem is probably in a different `urls.py`. If you're lucky, the full traceback might give you the exact line of the module where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Use url() to name the urls and try the following in template file.

`{% url 'artigos' %}`